# Reading EBNF Grammar

Tags: grammar, ebnf

I just needed help with reading this EBNF grammar, I'm new to it and don't particularly understand the first , I understand the second one but just don't understand how it ties in with the first one.

Term ::= Primary { (T_STAR|T_SLASH) Term }

Primary ::= T_ICONST | T_SCONST | T_ID | T_LPAREN Expr T_RPAREN

Comment: Take a look [here](http://matt.might.net/articles/grammars-bnf-ebnf/). It has a nice and simple explanation. the top rule means the symbol `Term` is converted to symbol `Primary` followed by the repetition of the symbols in curly braces zero or more times.

Comment: so it would be something likle "Term is defined as.. (everything in Primary) {(T_STAR|T_SLASH) Term} "   But now what does the second Term mean?

Comment: read the rule as `Term` can *go* to `right hand side`. It is more of a conversion rather than definition. The second rule just means the symbol `Primary` can be converted to either of the symbols separated by `|` in the right hand side of the rule.

Comment: i somewhat get it now, but lets say i wanted to parse Primary, how would i go along doing that.

Comment: You can replace it with any of the symbols in the right hand side of the rule. So in this case you can 4 ways to convert a `Primary`. An recursive parser checks the symbol against the rules and goes down the rule set until it either succeeds or fails

Answer (score -1):

In EBNF, expression surrounded by curl parenthesis could omit or repeat more time
so we can construct some code according to this EBNF(lets assume that T_STAR representing character "*" and T_SLASH for "/")

```
// Term ::= Primary { (T_STAR|T_SLASH) Term }
// Primary ::= T_ICONST | T_SCONST | T_ID | T_LPAREN Expr T_RPAREN
Term ::= Primary * Term
Term ::= Primary * Primary / Term
Term ::= Primary * Primary / Primary 
Term ::=  ThisIsT_ID * ThisIsT_ID / ThisIsT_ID
```